# get element id with vb

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code in an aspx page:

```
<div id="objectList" style="overflow: auto; width:100px; display:block;      
position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:100;">

<div id="object8" class="object" title="">
<br>object8</div>

<div id="object2" class="objectSelect" title="">
<br>object2</div>
</div>
```

I am attempting to find the ID of the object that is selected, in this case object2. I am trying to do it in the codebehind with vb.net but I'm not sure how. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `runat="server"` to all of the `<div>` elements you wish to find out if they are selected or not, like this:

```
<div id="object8" class="object" title="" runat="server">
<div id="object2" class="objectSelect" title="" runat="server">
```

Now in code-behind you can loop through all of the `<div>` elements in the page and check the `class` attribute value, like this:

```
For Each item As Control In Me.Controls
    ' We have to look at all HtmlGenericControl, because 
    ' there is no .NET control type for DIV 
    Dim theDiv As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl = TryCast(item, System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)

    ' Make sure the cast worked before we try to use the DIV
    If theDiv IsNot Nothing Then
        ' Is the class name equal to objectSelect?
        If theDiv.Attributes("class") = "objectSelect" Then
            ' Yes, this DIV is selected, do something here

        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. But the objectSelect changes based on which one is selected, how do I find out which one is selected? Something like Me.objectSelect?

Comment: Updated answer to provide what you were looking for, sorry I misread your original intent.